# Mysql group_concat with a many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've three tables

```
+-------------+  +-----------------------------+  +-----------+
| WORKSPACES  |  | USERS_WORKSPACES            |  | USERS     |
+-----+-------+  +----+---------+--------------+  +----+------+
| id  | title |  | id | user_id | workspace_id |  | id | name |
+-----+-------+  +----+---------+--------------+  +----+------+
|  1  |  W1   |  | 1  |   1     |     1        |  |  1 |  U1  |
|  2  |  W2   |  | 2  |   1     |     2        |  |  2 |  U2  |
|  3  |  W3   |  | 3  |   2     |     2        |  |  3 |  U3  |
+-----+-------+  +----+---------+--------------+  +----+------+
```

I'm trying to query the db to list unique workspaces for a given user_id. For each workspace returned I want a group of unique user ids. Like so:

For user_id = 2

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------+
| workspace_id | workspace_title | users |
+----------------------------------------+
| 1            | W1              | 1     |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2            | W2              | 1,2   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

For user_id = 2

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------+
| workspace_id | workspace_title | users |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2            | W2              | 1,2   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

With this query I can list unique user ids for all the workspaces. How can I limit the listing to only the workspaces associated with a specified user_id?

```
SELECT w.id,
       w.title,
       group_concat(b.user_id) as users
FROM   workspaces w, 
       users_workspaces b,
       users u
WHERE  w.id = b.workspace_id 
  AND  b.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY w.id
```

Comment: Note that `users_workspaces.id` appears to serve no useful purpose. And now see JOIN

Comment: I don;t understand the question, something like this? `.... where w.id = b.workspace_id and b.user_id = u.id and u.id = 2 ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query looked functionally correct.  However, you don't need to join in the `users` table, because you can get `user_id` from `users_workspaces`.  And, you should use proper join syntax:

```
select w.id, w.title, group_concat(uw.user_id) as users
from workspaces w join 
     users_workspaces uw
     on w.id = uw.workspace_id 
group by w.id;
```

If you want to limit this to workspaces associated with a particular user id, then use a `having` clause:

```
select w.id, w.title, group_concat(uw.user_id) as users
from workspaces w join 
     users_workspaces uw
     on w.id = uw.workspace_id 
group by w.id
having sum(uw.user_id = @USERID) > 0;
```

Comment: It works! Thanks, I was unaware of the having clause!

Answer (score 0):

try this -- you can substitute any value or variable for the user_id in the where clause.:

```
SELECT
w.id,
w.title,
group_concat(b.user_id) as users
FROM 
workspaces w 
JOIN users_workspaces b ON w.id = b.workspace_id 
JOIN users u ON b.user_id = u.id
where 
u.user_id = 2 
group by w.id
```